# Deleting head node of a linked list in C where every node knows its headlist

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, pointer-to-pointer

```
typedef struct node {
    int x;
    struct node *next;
    struct node **head;
} node;
```

Considering this struct, I've implemented a push function:

```
node *push(node *nodo, node *top) {
    nodo->next = top;
    top = nodo;
    nodo->head = &top;
    return top;
}
```

so that **every node** is aware of who is the current head list.
But I have some problems when I have to delete the head of the list:

```
node *delete(node *top, int x) {
    if (top->x == x)
        return pop(top);
    else
        return *other function*;
}

node *pop(node *top) {
    node *tmp = top;
    top = tmp->next;
    free(tmp);
    return top;
}
```

When printing head content, this will give me segmentation fault:

```
void print(node *top) {
    node *tmp = top;
    printf("List:\n");
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", (*((tmp)->head))->x);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    printf("\nEnd\n");
}
```

Comment: `nodo->head = &top;` is wrong. it sets the current node's `head` pointer to the address of a temporary that will expire the moment the function exits, leaving a dangling pointer to nowhere.

Comment: It just works fine when i print my list after calling push functions. @WhozCraig

Comment: Why does `pop` (and sometimes `delete`) return a pointer to a freed node?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Please explain in your question why you need a reference to the head in all nodes. `struct node** head;` seems to be the address of a pointer to the head node, so you could simply modify the head pointer. (This is based on guessing because you didn't show how you call your functions.

Comment: *"It just works fine"* - So long as you don't actually *use* that `head` member by you're stuffing in every node in any fashion involving a dereference, it certainly can otherwise "work fine" and have no issues. But that `head` member is nonetheless set to what is ultimately a dangling address. If you *ever* dereference it you *will* invoke UB.

Comment: Right, that was the point, thanks, @WhozCraig!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I have some problems when I have to delete the head of the list

You have much worse and more pervasive problems.

Here ...

> ```
> node* push(node* nodo, node* top){
>   nodo->next=top;
>   top = nodo;
>   nodo->head = &top;
>   return top;
> }
> ```

You set `nodo->head` to point to a parameter of the function.  The lifetime of that parameter ends when the function returns, at which time the node's `head` pointer becomes invalid.  Undefined behavior results from any subsequent attempt to use the node's `head` pointer in any way.

I suppose that you have defined `node.head` as a double pointer so as to be able to change the head node in one place for all nodes.  In that case, you need to choose a "one place" that is in fact the same for every node and whose lifetime does not end before that of the overall list does.  Having chosen such a location, you would pass it itself to `push`:

```
node* push(node* nodo, node** top){
  nodo->next = *top;
  nodo->head = top;
  *top = nodo;
  return *top;
}
```

Of course, all callers would need to be updated appropriately.

However, if you want to have this kind of association between nodes and the list to which they belong, then you should consider creating a separate data structure for the list itself, and giving the nodes a poiunter to *that*.  That would solve several problems for you.

Example:

```
typedef struct node{
  int x;
  struct node* next;
  struct list* list;
}node;

struct list {
    node *head;
    // maybe other whole-list information, too, such as the tail node
    // or an element count
};
```

The `struct list` objects then provide the place for head node pointers to be recorded, and nodes can access their lists' head node via the list.

Comment: Your `push()` looks wrong. The body should be using `*top`.

Comment: Thank you, @IanAbbott.  How shockingly sloppy that was of me.  Fixed now.

Comment: Not quite fixed. You want `nodo->head = top;`. The return value is a bit superfluous.

Comment: Really fixed, now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JohnBollinger! I didn't figured out why the use of a `&var` is so **dangerous** in a function where `var` is a parameter of it. Solved.